# index merge vs multi-column index

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

So I have this query:

```
UPDATE ref_records SET count = count + 1 WHERE ref_url = 'http://www.example.com/' AND user_id = '32366' LIMIT 1
```

I have indexes set on each "ref_url" and "user_id" respectively. However, MySQL explain shows that it's merging the indexes:

```
Using intersect(user_id,ref_url); Using where
```

But why doesn't it do so in their actual column order (ref_url, user_id) ?
Also, would it help optimize this query by adding an index on (ref_url,user_id) or index on (user_id,ref_url) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Using intersect` is almost always an indication that you should have a "composite" index on the columns mentioned.

In your case, the index can be either of these:

```
INDEX(user_id, ref_url)
INDEX(ref_url, user_id)
```

The order of clauses in the `WHERE` does not matter -- the Optimizer is free to reorder things.  It does *not* matter to the optimization.

On the other hand, the order of columns in a composite index *does* matter.  (But it does not happen to matter in this case.)

Further explanation:  For the "intersect" technique, this happens:

1. Find all entires in `INDEX(user_id)` for 32366; collect the `PRIMARY KEYs` for those rows.
2. Find all entries in `INDEX(ref_urs)` for 'http...'; collect the `PRIMARY KEYs` for those rows.
3. Using those two lists, "intersect" them.  That is, find out what entries are common to both.
4. Now, reach for the desired rows by using the `PRIMARY KEYs`.

With a composite index:

1. Drill down the BTree directly to the desired row(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed explanation. Much clear now!